# Codeigniter JavaScript Success Message Issue

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

When I insert or edit form I showing success message. That is INSERTED SUCCESS or UPDATED SUCCESS in view page i am showing.

Form view page I am moving to edit page,  in edit page if I click cancel button I redirect to view page that time same message INSERTED SUCCESS OR UPDATED SUCCESS message showing.

How to avoid this, once I showed success message it should not come again.

```
 if (confirmed)
    {

    $.ajax({ 
        type:'POST',
        url:"<?=site_url('ProcCtr/PurchaseQuotation_Delete')?>",
        data:{'id':a},
        success:function(response){
        if(response==1){
            $('#errorStatus').hide();                           
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-success"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Success!</strong> A Record is Deleted Successfully.</div>');
        }else{
            $('#errorStatus').show();
            $('#alert').append('<div class="alert alert-danger "><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">&times;</a><strong>Failure!</strong> A Record is Unable To Delete</div>');
        }
        $('#dataRespTable').dataTable().fnDraw();
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#alert').empty(); }, 8000);
                    }
                    });


                // window.location.href = link;     
            }
```

Comment: I m waiting for solution to solve.

Comment: I have provided a basic example. Hope this helps. You have to setup as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

This because once alert Message shown before automatic hide or my self Cancel the alert message I am click on Add or Edit page button.

So it remains same in view page, once time out for flash alert time it wont come again.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
<?php
class brand extends CI_Controller{
     function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('brand');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function ajax_submit()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        /*--- here goes your database update or edit script*/
        if(//database update successful)
        {
           echo "Update Successful";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "Update Failed";
        }
   }

}
```

Now in the brand.php view file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#sub_but").click(function()
   {
     var username = $("#username").val();
     var password = $("#password").val();
     $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>branch/ajax_submit",
            {
             'username':username,
             'password':password
            },
            function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
   });
});
</script>

<form name="submit_form" action="" method="post">
   <input name="username" id="username" value=""/>
   <input name="password" id="password" value=""/>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" name="sub_but" id="sub_but"/>
</form>
```

Check one thing, though I am using a form, I am not using submit button. 
So the form isn't being actually submitted. The button click event calls the $.post method to make an ajax call.